# Retrieving Contact.Email, Opportunity.Name and OpportunityLineItem.Quantity in one query

Tags: salesforce, soql

I'm trying to retrieve Contact.Email, Opportunity.Name and OpportunityLineItem.Quantity in a single SOQL query. Is this possible? If so, how?

My query is:

```
Select Opportunity.Id, Opportunity.Name, Contact.Email, (Select Quantity From OpportunityLineItem) From OpportunityContactRole Limit 10
```

My main objective is to get elements from OpportunityContactRole and OpportunityLineItem in a single query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close :)

```
SELECT Id, Name,
    (SELECT Quantity FROM OpportunityLineItems),
    (SELECT Contact.Email FROM OpportunityContactRoles)
FROM Opportunity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT Opportunity.Name, Contact.Email, Contact.Id FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE Opportunity.Id = '<OppId>'LIMIT 1
```